# Como fazer checkbox se comportarem como radio em ng-repeat?

Tags: html5, angularjs

Eu estou tentando fazer com que um checkbox se comporte como um radio, mas não estou conseguindo vi alguns exemplo mas não entendi como funciona. Se alguém puder me ajudar. Agradeço desde já pela atenção!

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.pp = ["feminino", "masculino", "outros"];
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.1.x" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.1.5"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <h1> ng-repeat </h1>
  <div data-ng-repeat="p in pp">
    <input type="checkbox"> 
    {{p}}
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Que você selecione um e desmarque os outros?

Comment: Isso, que nunca fique mais de uma opção selecionada.

Answer (score 1):

Crie uma variável de controle, onde o valor do item selecionado ficará com padrão e depois da ação do `click` somente o item selecionado é o único com seleção. Isso tudo só ocorre se o click da seleção for para checar o elemento ao contrário ficam todos sem seleção. É a maneira simples de resolver esse problema.

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.pp = ["feminino", "masculino", "outros"];
  $scope.checkName = '';
  $scope.setCheckName = function(name){
    $scope.checkName = name;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js">
</script>
<h1>ng-repeat </h1>
<div data-ng-app="plunker" data-ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div data-ng-repeat="p in pp">
    <input type="checkbox" 
      data-ng-click="setCheckName(p)"
      data-ng-checked="p==checkName">
    {{p}}
  </div>
</div>
```

***Observações:***

- O nome do seu `module` poderia ser `app` com o mesmo nome da variável
- O nome do seu `controller` deveria começar com minusculo tipo `mainCtrl`.
- Um exemplo de nome sugestivos no caso do meu exemplo é `checkName` e `setCheckName` isso é bom para relacionar o que está fazendo.

Comment: Muito obrigada! eu esqueci de agradecer. funcionou.